# mysqli prepared statement without bind_param

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this code for selecting `fname` from the latest record on the user table.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
$sdt=$mysqli->('SELECT fname FROM user ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1');
$sdt->bind_result($code);
$sdt->fetch();
echo $code ;
```

I used prepared statement with `bind_param` earlier, but for now in the above code for first time I want to use prepared statement without binding parameters and I do not know how to select from table without using `bind_param()`. How to do that?

Answer (score 9):

If, like in your case, there is nothing to bind, then just use `query()`

```
$res = $mysqli->query('SELECT fname FROM user ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1');
$fname = $res->fetch_row()[0] ?? false;
```

But if even a single variable is going to be used in the query, then you must substitute it with a placeholder and therefore prepare your query.

However, in 2022 and beyond, (starting PHP 8.1) you can indeed skip `bind_param` even for a prepared query, sending variables directly to `execute()`, in the form of array:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `customers` WHERE `Customer_ID`=?";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute([$_POST['ID']]);
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer ticked is open to SQL injection. What is the point of using a prepared statement and not correctly preparing the data. You should never just put a string in the query line. The point of a prepared statement is that it is prepared. Here is one example

```
$query = "SELECT `Customer_ID`,`CompanyName` FROM `customers` WHERE `Customer_ID`=?";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('i',$_POST['ID']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id,$CompanyName);
```

In Raffi's code you should do this

```
$bla = $_POST['something'];
$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `fname` FROM `user` WHERE `bla` = ? ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bind_param('s',$_POST['something']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($code);
$stmt->fetch();
echo $code;
```

Please be aware I don't know if your post data is a string or an integer. If it was an integer you would put

```
$stmt->bind_param('i',$_POST['something']);
```

instead. I know you were saying without bind param, but trust me that is really really bad if you are taking in input from a page, and not preparing it correctly first.

Comment: `What is the point of using a prepared statement and not correctly preparing the data.` I am having this same issue where there are no parameters whatsoever to bind. It is a joined query that gets what it needs from a secondary query but not sure how to execute it in prepared statement format when there is nothing to prepare in order to get results without using `query();`.